# Displaying user's default image with User Picture Field module

Tags: theming

I am installing the User Picture Field module to take over the Drupal default user picture but it does not display the default user image when empty (D7, Bartik.)

What snippet should I add to the *page--user--edit.tpl.php* template so that the uploaded user picture is displayed **OR** the default "nophoto.jpg" file **when the user has NOT uploaded a picture.**

I can do the first part and display the uploaded picture but I can't get the "nophoto.jpg" to display. The "nophoto.jpg" is located in *public://pictures/nophoto.jpg* and I do not use image styles.

Any and all help is appreciated.  Thank you :)

Comment: As far as I'm aware that module should handle defaults for you. Have you also tried posting a bug report or support request to that module's issue queue?

Comment: Yes, I have posted a bug report although i am not sure it is a bug. Indeed, the default "no photo" image displays only when the user picture field is empty. Once a fid is assigned to the image, the field is no longer empty and the default"nophoto" is treated like and uploaded image.

Comment: @user14666, Its bug or ?